# Stored Procedure parameter in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Below I have a query that I am working on that will create a stored procedure.

```
USE [PERFORMANCE]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[proc_performance_employee_manager_relation]    ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_performance_employee_manager_relation] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @beginDate datetime,
    @endDate datetime

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PERFORMANCE TABLE 
(
AGT_RESPONSIBLE INT,
EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
#_OF_COMPLIMENTS INT,
DEBIT_COUNT INT,
DEBIT_POTENTIAL_AMOUNT INT,
DEBIT_TNT_AMT INT,
#_OF_VALUE_ADDS INT,
DOLLAR_AMT_OF_VALUE_ADDS INT
)

INSERT INTO @PERFORMANCE
Exec proc_performance_AGT_roi '2015-05-01','2015-05-30'

SELECT
P.AGT_RESPONSIBLE, 
P.EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME ,
P.EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME ,
P.#_OF_COMPLIMENTS ,
P.DEBIT_COUNT ,
P.DEBIT_POTENTIAL_AMOUNT ,
P.DEBIT_TNT_AMT ,
P.#_OF_VALUE_ADDS, 
P.DOLLAR_AMT_OF_VALUE_ADDS,
AGENT.EMPLOYEE_ID,
AGENT.FIRST_NAME,
AGENT.LAST_NAME,
AGENT.INTERNAL_TITLE,
AGENT.BRANCH_CODE,
AGENT.LOCATION,
MANAGER.EMPLOYEE_ID,
MANAGER.FIRST_NAME,
MANAGER.LAST_NAME,
MANAGER.INTERNAL_TITLE,
MANAGER.BRANCH_CODE,
MANAGER.LOCATION


FROM 
@PERFORMANCE P
LEFT JOIN omadb08.TANDT_EMPLOYEE.dbo.ADP_EMPLOYEE AGENT
    LEFT JOIN omadb08.TANDT_EMPLOYEE.dbo.ADP_EMPLOYEE MANAGER
    ON AGENT.REPORTS_TO_EMPLOYEE_ID = MANAGER.EMPLOYEE_ID
ON P.AGT_RESPONSIBLE = AGENT.EMPLOYEE_ID


END


GO
```

The code works fine, but my main concern is in the code where I have parameters:

```
INSERT INTO @PERFORMANCE
Exec proc_performance_AGT_roi '2015-05-01','2015-05-30'
```

The above is an insert from another procedure. My concern is that if I were to run this in a month, it will use these dates as a parameter and not ones that I will want. So is there a way that if I were to put the parameters in the overall procedure, it can copy what I inputed into that exec statement so the procedure will work, or is that just a fantasy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question. If what you are asking is - can you use the input parameters for a stored procedure as input parameters to another, then yes, you can.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_performance_employee_manager_relation] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @beginDate datetime,
    @endDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
   ...
    INSERT INTO @PERFORMANCE
    Exec proc_performance_AGT_roi @beginDate ,@endDate 
   ...
END
```

The stored procedure `proc_performance_employee_manager_relation` can be executed elsewhere with any parameters you desire.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate='01/01/2015'
SET @EndDate='06/01/205'

EXEC proc_performance_employee_manager_relation @StartDate, @EndDate
```

Also, the locale in which the server is configured may be different than the way you are use to entering the date. Look at some examples on [this](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) page. You can force a specific conversion using functions such as:

```
-- SQL convert date string to datetime - time set to 00:00:00.000 or 12:00AM    
PRINT CONVERT(datetime,'07-10-2012',110)        -- Jul 10 2012 12:00AM    
PRINT CONVERT(datetime,'2012/07/10',111)        -- Jul 10 2012 12:00AM
PRINT CONVERT(datetime,'20120710',  112)        -- Jul 10 2012 12:00AM
```

Comment: When I changed it to the answer you provided, it gave me this:

Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Comment: Updated with specific cast functions

Answer (score 1):

You need in parameters. Here is a stored procedure with an in parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetAddress @City nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address
WHERE City = @City
GO
```

and this is how you call it:

```
EXEC uspGetAddress @City = 'New York'
```

You just need to modify your stored procedure to expect in parameters and call it with the necessary parameters when you call it.